# Determining Whether a Wall is Displayed as Cut or in Full in Revit API on a Plan View

Tags: revit-api

Stack Overflow community!

I'm working with the Revit API and facing a challenge in differentiating how walls are displayed on a specific plan view. Specifically, I need to distinguish between walls that are shown as cut (intersected by the view's cut plane) and those that are displayed in full because they are entirely above or below the cut plane.

Here's the context of my problem:

- I have a plan view (ViewPlan) in Revit.
- There are multiple walls, some of which intersect with the view's cut plane, while others are completely above or below this plane.
- I need to programmatically determine which walls are displayed as cut and which are displayed in full in this view.

I've attempted to analyze the walls' top and base offsets compared to the view's cut level, but I'm unsure if this is the right approach or if there's a more efficient way to achieve this in the Revit API.

Here's a snippet of my current approach in C#:

```cs
ViewPlan viewPlan = ...; // The plan view in question
PlanViewRange viewRange = viewPlan.GetViewRange();
Level cutLevel = ...; // The cut level of the view

foreach (Wall wall in walls) // Assuming we have a list of walls
{
    double wallTop = wall.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.WALL_TOP_OFFSET).AsDouble();
    double wallBase = wall.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.WALL_BASE_OFFSET).AsDouble();
    
    if (wallBase < cutLevel.Elevation && wallTop > cutLevel.Elevation)
    {
        // The wall is displayed as cut
    }
    else
    {
        // The wall is displayed in full or not displayed
    }
}
```

Is there a more direct or accurate way to determine the display style (cut or full) of walls in a plan view using the Revit API? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may be a little better off using `get_BoundingBox()` since this will give you the absolute coordinates. The parameters that you are getting may be relative to their host, which could be some other level and give you unexpected results that you will have to correct by subtracting out the host elevation.

```cs
double wallTop = wall.get_BoundingBox(viewPlan).Min.Z;
double wallBase = wall.get_BoundingBox(viewPlan).Max.Z;
```

That said, what you have should also work if you are willing to deal with the relative elevation issue.